# PHP DocuSign: getting empty document when downloading the completed signed document

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, jwt, docusignapi

I integrated Docusing with a PHP Laravel App using JWT Auth. It's working perfectly, could send the email to recipients for signing. Now after all signing is done we would like to download the complete signed document with CoC.

I'm using following code to get the signed document for a specific Envelope:

```
$envelope_api = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

$tmpFile = $envelope_api->getDocument($account_id, 'combined', $envelope_id);

$savCert = file_put_contents("signed_document.pdf", file_get_contents($tmpFile->getPathname()));
```

But I'm getting the empty document when the file is downloaded. It would very helpful if you could give a hint how to resolve the issue.

json payload for a $tmpfile:

```
object(SplFileObject)#418 (5) 
{
 ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(44) "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\19F.tmp" 
 ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(7) "19F.tmp" 
 ["openMode":"SplFileObject":private]=> string(1) "r" 
 ["delimiter":"SplFileObject":private]=> string(1) "," 
 ["enclosure":"SplFileObject":private]=> string(1) """ 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in version 6.5 of the SDK
Version 6.5.1 has the fix. Please update your package and try again.

If you use 6.5 you will need to add these lines:

```
$tmpFile = $envelopeApi->getDocument($account_id, 'combined', $envelope_id);
$tmpFile->rewind();
$contents = $tmpFile->fread($tmpFile->fstat()['size']);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for letting me know the bug issue. I've updated the version and it's working as expected. Just one thing, 'combined' should include the signed document with CoC, right? But it's only downloading the complete signed document. We need the CoC too. Thanks again!

Comment: try to use "certificate" and see if that's what you need

Comment: Yes, I tried with 'certificate' and it download the certificate only. Thanks